# Updating .Net Functions App to .Net 7 causing library errors

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

I've updated all my other projects to net7.0 no problem but my Functions project is throwing library errors on runtime (it builds without error) such as:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=7.0.0.0
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0
```

I've tried updating the csproj to explicity include those libraries like so:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0.0" />
```

But the latest version for that package is 2.2.0 so I don't know why it's looking for 7.0.0.0?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions
Explicitly adding 2.2.0 in csproj doesn't work either

Comment: Are you running in Isolated mode? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/announcing-the-net-7-for-azure-functions-isolated-worker-process/ba-p/3671398

Comment: Migrating to isolated worked, thanks!